# Equations of Elastic net regularization

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, elastic-net

I know that the Elastic net takes care of the limitations of Lasso by adding an L 2 penalty term. In the attached picture has been mentioned that the two formulas are equivalent. I tried to show this, but I failed.

Could you please help me to see how these two equations are equivariant?

[image]